# How to tell what USB device caused bluescreen

Tags: windows-7, usb, crash, bsod, debug

I've got a mini dump from when my computer bluescreened.  The debugger shows that it was a generic usb driver that caused the crash, but how to tell which one?  This is the first time it's bluescreened and I've not added any new devices.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\d_harding\Downloads\080413-30045-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?fffff8a0`0021ec32?
DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?fffff8a0`01e91022?
DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?fffff800`00b9c3c0?
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: srv*
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.18113.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130318-1533
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`03007000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`0324a670
Debug session time: Sun Aug  4 19:54:25.482 2013 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:21:51.310
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.........................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
...............
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, fffffa8008628a00, fffff80000b9c3d8, fffffa8008c258d0}

Probably caused by : usbccgp.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time (usually 10 minutes).
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa8008628a00, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff80000b9c3d8, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa8008c258d0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  usbccgp.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d8c0c0a

MODULE_NAME: usbccgp

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff88006a81000 usbccgp

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_c000000f:  FFFFF80000BA2FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00b9c388 fffff800`030ec8c2 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`08628a00 fffff800`00b9c3d8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9c390 fffff800`0308784c : fffff800`00b9c5b0 fffff800`00b9c5b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x33af0
fffff800`00b9c430 fffff800`030876e6 : fffff800`0322cf20 00000000`00014859 00000000`00000000 fffff880`02d1917e : nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable+0x6c
fffff800`00b9c4a0 fffff800`030875ce : 00000003`0d9a086f fffff800`00b9cb18 00000000`00014859 fffff800`031fada8 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0xc6
fffff800`00b9caf0 fffff800`030873b7 : 00000000`ec23f8cb 00000000`00014859 00000000`ec23f811 00000000`00000059 : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9cb90 fffff800`0307490a : fffff800`031f7e80 fffff800`03205cc0 00000000`00000000 fffff880`02c26588 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9cc40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`00b9d000 fffff800`00b97000 fffff800`00b9cc00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_lvuvc64_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_lvuvc64_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> lmvm usbccgp
start             end                 module name
fffff880`06a81000 fffff880`06a9e000   usbccgp    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\sym\usbccgp.pdb\E57A861FA09D4D178C69ABB0A6F4868C1\usbccgp.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: usbccgp.sys
    Mapped memory image file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\sym\usbccgp.sys\4D8C0C0A1d000\usbccgp.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\usbccgp.sys
    Image name: usbccgp.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Mar 24 23:29:14 2011 (4D8C0C0A)
    CheckSum:         0001B399
    ImageSize:        0001D000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17586
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17586
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     USBCCGP.SYS
    OriginalFilename: USBCCGP.SYS
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17586
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17586 (win7sp1_gdr.110324-1501)
    FileDescription:  USB Common Class Generic Parent Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Why does your computer not have a machine name?  What version of Windows 7 do you have, your kernel version, contains the word "Free" which is odd.

Comment: upload the dump. Telling you all instructions can be difficult to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**lvuvc64.sys** is driver for your `Logitech Webcam`. So look for a driver update:

> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: X64_0x9F_3_**lvuvc64**_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

still upload the dmp so that I can verify this.

Comment: Not to be a total noob, but how do I go about doing that?  I see that a quick google search of lvuvc64 turns up results for logitech.  Is there a point in my uploading the dump?

Comment: from the Memory.dmp I can see the file version of the driver and the correct device name. But you can also look for a new driver at the logitech websites. Also try to disable powersaving for the Webcam and USB ports.

Answer (score 2):

Many USB devices expose multiple USB interfaces. In USB terminology, these devices are called composite devices. Microsoft Windows 2000 and Windows 98 operating systems include a generic parent facility in the USB bus driver (Usbhub.sys) that exposes each interface of the composite device as a separate device. In Microsoft Windows XP and Windows Me, this facility is streamlined and improved by transferring it to an independent driver called the USB generic parent driver (Usbccgp.sys). Using the features of the generic parent driver, device vendors can make selective use of Microsoft-supplied driver support for some interfaces.

It wasn't a "single" USB port that caused the crash but rather the "parent driver". I would recommend just re installing the driver.